# C Code and it C++ Translation Initializing Differently

Tags: c, c++11, initialization

I have an old C code that I am rewriting in C++11. In the older C code (which is a console application) has a `struct` that is a global variable in the file TC.C; the struct in question is

```
typedef struct 
{
   char* m_szTabName;         
   char* m_szCWName;          
   FILE* m_fpCWFile;          
   double* m_dNatCost;        
   double* m_dStateCost;      
   double* m_dLocalCost;      
   short m_nDateRanges;       
   short m_sNumCodes;         
   GTIME* m_gStart;           
   GTIME* m_gEnd;             
   short* m_sIcdVsn;          
   short* m_sIcdEdn;          
   MapRecord** m_tIcdMap;     
   FileHeader m_tHdr;         
   CodeHeader m_tDxTab;       
   CodeHeader m_tPrTab;       
   CCMatrixHeader m_tCCMatTab;
   NeoHeader m_tNeoTab;       
   DRGHeader m_tDRGTab;       
   CCHeader m_tCCTab;         
   CCExclHeader m_tCCExclTab; 
   LogicHeader m_tLogic;        
   CodeRecord* m_tCodeRec;    
   char* m_szLabStore;        
} Grouper;
```

In the C code this `struct` is *not* initialised and is used as follows

```
#include "tabcomp.h"
#include "OtherHeaderFiles"
...
Grouper tgLoc;
...
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fpOut, *fpIn;
    ...
    CreateCodeTable(fpIn, &tgLoc.m_tDxTab, (int)DX_LAB);   
    ...
}
```

So the `Grouper tgLoc` does not get initialised and upon the call to `CreateCodeTable` the values in `tgLoc` are

```
tgLoc  Grouper:
+       m_szTabName     0x00000000 <NULL> char *
+       m_szCWName      0x00000000 <NULL> char *
+       m_fpCWFile      0x00000000 <NULL> _iobuf *
+       m_dNatCost      0x00000000 {???} double *
+       m_dStateCost    0x00000000 {???} double *
+       m_dLocalCost    0x00000000 {???} double *
+       m_nDateRanges   0 short
+       m_sNumCodes     0 short
+       m_gStart        0x00000000 {???} long *
+       m_gEnd          0x00000000 {???} long *
+       m_sIcdVsn       0x00000000 {???} short *
+       m_sIcdEdn       0x00000000 {???} short *
+       m_tIcdMap       0x00000000 {???} TMapRec * *
+       m_tHdr          {m_sCreateDate=0x00e80150 "" m_usRefID=0 m_cHiByte=0 '\0' ...} FileHeader
+       m_tDxTab        {m_ucCodeLen=0 '\0' m_usNumHdr=0 m_usNumCodes=0 ...} CodeHeader
+       m_tPrTab        {m_ucCodeLen=0 '\0' m_usNumHdr=0 m_usNumCodes=0 ...} CodeHeader
+       m_tCCMatTab     {m_ucNRow=0 '\0' m_ucNCol=0 '\0' m_cpCCMatrix=0x00000000 <NULL> } CCMatrixHeader
+       m_tNeoTab       {m_usNumCodes=0 m_ucNeoVal=0x00000000 <NULL> } TNeoHdr
+       m_tDRGTab       {m_usNumDRG=0 m_usNumBits=0 m_bBitVals=0x00000000 {???} ...} DRGHeader
+       m_tCCTab        {m_usNumCodes=0 m_ucSep=0x00000000 <NULL> m_useCCRow=0x00000000 {???} } CCHeader
+       m_tCCExclTab    {m_usNumCCHdr=0 m_usNumCCTail=0 m_usLowPDX=0x00000000 {???} ...} CCExclHeader
+       m_tLogic        {wFldErr=0 wDefLen=0 wFldLen=0 ...} LogicHeader
+       m_tCodeRec      0x00000000 <NULL> CodeRecord *
+       m_szLabStore    0x00000000 <NULL> char *
```

Now, I have moved the code from the C application to a C++11 application. The code runs fine, but the value of `tgLoc` upon the call to `CreateCodeTable` is now

```
tgLoc Grouper:
+       m_szTabName     0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> char *
+       m_szCWName      0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> char *
+       m_fpCWFile      0xcdcdcdcd {_ptr=??? _cnt=??? _base=??? ...} _iobuf *
+       m_dNatCost      0xcdcdcdcd {???} double *
+       m_dStateCost    0xcdcdcdcd {???} double *
+       m_dLocalCost    0xcdcdcdcd {???} double *
        m_nDateRanges   -12851 short
        m_sNumCodes     -12851 short
+       m_gStart        0xcdcdcdcd {???} long *
+       m_gEnd          0xcdcdcdcd {???} long *
+       m_sIcdVsn       0xcdcdcdcd {???} short *
+       m_sIcdEdn       0xcdcdcdcd {???} short *
+       m_tIcdMap       0xcdcdcdcd {???} MapRecord * *
+       m_tHdr          {m_sCreateDate=0x27570cc0 "ÍÍÍÍÍÍ... m_usRefID=52685 m_cHiByte=-51 'Í' ...} FileHeader
+       m_tDxTab        {m_ucCodeLen=205 'Í' m_usNumHdr=52685 m_usNumCodes=52685 ...} CodeHeader
+       m_tPrTab        {m_ucCodeLen=205 'Í' m_usNumHdr=52685 m_usNumCodes=52685 ...} CodeHeader
+       m_tCCMatTab     {m_ucNRow=205 'Í' m_ucNCol=205 'Í' m_cpCCMatrix=0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> } CCMatrixHeader
+       m_tNeoTab       {m_usNumCodes=52685 m_ucNeoVal=0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> } NeoHeader
+       m_tDRGTab       {m_usNumDRG=52685 m_usNumBits=52685 m_bBitVals=0xcdcdcdcd {???} ...} DRGHeader
+       m_tCCTab        {m_usNumCodes=52685 m_ucSep=0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> m_useCCRow=0xcdcdcdcd {...} } CCHeader
+       m_tCCExclTab    {m_usNumCCHdr=52685 m_usNumCCTail=52685 m_usLowPDX=0xcdcdcdcd {???} ...} CCExclHeader
+       m_tLogic        {wFldErr=52685 wDefLen=52685 wFldLen=52685 ...} LogicHeader
+       m_tCodeRec      0xcdcdcdcd {szCode=0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> ucFldNum=??? ucFldType=??? ...} CodeRecord *
+       m_szLabStore    0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.> char *
```

There is only a small amound of code before the call to `CreateCodeTable` and this does *not* initialise `tgLoc`, so my question is, why is the new code compiled under C++11 initialising differently to the older C code and how can I initialise the new code so that `tgLoc` contains the same values as the old code for it first use?

*I am aware that `0xCDCDCDCD` is a debugging value that comes from the bowels of the C runtime library. When you allocate a block of memory in a debug build, it's initialized to this spurious value in the hope of catching bugs. `0xCDCDCDCD` is non-NULL and is never a valid memory pointer. But this seems to be affecting the output of the `CreateCodeTable` method. i also don't understand why this value is being initialised like C when it is being compiled as C++11?* [Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1198/c/c1198.aspx)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: in your C++11 version, declare string fields like `std::string m_szTabName;` inside your `Grouper` struct. Also, compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I am doing this translation (`char*` -> `std::string`) in most places, but the code I have inherited is MASSIVE. I am trying to keep structs like this (which are used heavily) untouched to avoid excessive rewrites...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The -Wextra option is giving a `Error 1 error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wextra' ...` error in VS2013.

Comment: I was suggesting to compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Use a recent version (at least 4.8.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So the Grouper tgLoc does not get initialised

**Yes it is.**  It's a a global and as such is initialized to 0, which is what you can see.  From 6.7.8 of the C 99 Draft Standard:

> 10) If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has *static storage duration* is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>     rules.

The rules determining what "static storage duration" are are spelled out in section 6.2, in this case 6.2.4.3, "An object whose identifier is *declared with external or internal linkage* or with the
storage-class specifier static *has static storage duration*".

A file scope identifier *without* the keyword `static` (aka., a global) has *external* linkage.

> I have moved the code from the C application to a C++11 application. The code runs fine, but the value of tgLoc upon the call to CreateCodeTable is now

Most likely because now it's really *not* initialized, and so contains pseudo-junk provided by the OS (or real junk, provided from RAM, or the debugging value you refer to).  This implies it is no longer a global (local variables have no linkage and thus "automatic storage duration", so are not implicitly initialized -- this applies in both C and C++). In any case, you can initialize to 0 with:

```
Grouper tgLoc = { 0 };
```

This applies to all members, not just the first one.  In C++, just `= { }` is fine.

In case this is not clear: if you want a struct full of zeros, it must be initialized that way, either explicitly or *implicitly* as in the first case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. When I say initialized - I mean explicitly; as you later go on to clarify. I will test this out, again thanks.

Comment: I found some paragraphs from the C standard and added those if there's any doubt.

Comment: "*Under C++11, just `= { }` is fine.*" That's fine under any revision of C++, not just C++11. :-]